# Frustrating Syntax Issues with passing values into methods

Tags: java

I needed to rewrite a java program I had already completed to now include a class I would be able to test with using JUnit4. Unfortunately I can't even get to that point because I'm receiving an error. It's a really simple program where I ask the user for 3 numbers, pass those values into a function that does some calculations and should return a print statement with the value back. I made it work without the function and I'm having trouble with the syntax and fully understanding what I can and can't do with methods.

Here it is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Given ax^2 + bx^2 + c = 0");
        System.out.println("Please enter 'a', 'b', and 'c' to determine if there are any roots: ");
        float numA = kybd.nextFloat();
        float numB = kybd.nextFloat();
        float numC = kybd.nextFloat();

        quadraticAnswer(numA, numB, numC);

    }

    public static void float quadraticAnswer (float numA, float numB, float numC){
        float discriminant = ((numB*numB)-(4*numA*numC));

        if (discriminant < 0){
            System.out.println("The Equation has no roots!");
        }

        else if (discriminant ==0) {
            float root = (-numB + Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*numA);
            System.out.println("The Equation has one root: "+ root);
        }

        else {
            float root1 = (-numB + Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*numA);
            float root2 = (-numB - Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*numA);
            System.out.println("The Equation has two roots: " + root1 + " and " + root2 + ".");
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: If you're receiving an error, it's because you did something wrong.  If you'd like us to be more specific about what you did wrong, please be more specific about the error you got.  Please don't post questions that say "I got an error" without telling us what the error is.

Comment: If the discriminant is 0, there's no need to take the square root of it.

Comment: This question is about Java at its most basic, and the true solution is not to ask about such things here, but rather to study the very rudiments of the language. If you don't take this important step, you risk a lot of pain and frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the invalid syntax of

```
public static void float quadraticAnswer
```

to

```
public static void quadraticAnswer
```

as you are not returning anything.

If you use an IDE like Eclipse it will quickly highlight such errors

Comment: Thank you. So if I have this right, I should not put a data type in a method if I don't return anything?

Comment: If you do not return anything then state the return as void

Comment: @kingsman void means that you wish your method not to return anything, otherwise if you would like to get a result back from the method you declare its type